# To change number format of excel

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to change the number of excel when exporting from grid in asp.net.
In Grid the values displays 200.00 or 0.00 in excel it displays 200 or 0.I want display as 200.00 or 0.00.

This is the code i'm using:

```
HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Charset = "";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", "Supply/DemandReport.xls"));
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
gdSupplyorDemand.AllowPaging = false;
gdSupplyorDemand.HeaderStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
int location = int.Parse( ddlLocation.SelectedValue);
int ProductType = int.Parse(dpProductType.SelectedValue);
MastersClient DemandReport = new MastersClient();
DataSet ds = DemandReport.GetSupplyorDemandReport(ProductType, location);
gdSupplyorDemand.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
gdSupplyorDemand.DataBind();
form.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
form.Controls.Add(gdSupplyorDemand);
this.Controls.Add(form);
form.RenderControl(hw);
string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-form at:\@;}</style>";
Response.Write(style);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: What excel library are you using to generate the excel-file? Or are you exporting it as html with an excel-extension? However, normally it's better to use the `DataSource` of the grid to generate the excel-file instead of the `GridView`-html. Then you can do the formatting with the original data and the real types instead of interpreting strings in HTML.

Comment: @TimSchmelter u can see my edited code

Comment: You could provide an event handler for the `GridView` `RowDataBound` event- which is triggered for every row in the grid right after you've called `gdSupplyorDemand.DataBind();`. Then you can format the value and assign it to the cell's text like you want. Or you could manilpulate the `DataTable` or the query that fills the `DataTable` with the values you want to see.